# Unable to connect to AWS redshift via Meltano

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, shopify, etl, meltano

hope you all are doing great.

Can any one support me with an issue regarding Meltano? I want to perform EL (Extract Load) where I extract data from shopify and load it to AWS Redshift. To extract data from Shopify, I am using tap-shopify extractor which I have configured and tested successfully. At the moment, I am having issue with AWS redshift loader (target-redshift). I have set the credentials for the loader but I am unable to connect Meltano to my redshift cluster.

I am slightly new to AWS, therefore, my configuration might be wrong. Mentioned below is the error log when I try to run an EL pipeline. Would really appreciate it if someone could provide support.

Error:

```
2022-03-17T07:37:01.168162Z [info     ] Running extract & load...      job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=meltano run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a
2022-03-17T07:37:01.517719Z [warning  ] No state was found, complete import.
2022-03-17T07:37:04.791492Z [info     ] INFO GET https://monndaine.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-04/shop.json cmd_type=extractor job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=tap-shopify run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.491483Z [info     ] time=2022-03-17 00:37:05 name=target_redshift level=INFO message=Getting catalog objects from table cache... cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.529167Z [info     ] Traceback (most recent call last): cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.530526Z [info     ]   File "/home/zaki1272/meltano-projects/my-meltano-project/.meltano/loaders/target-redshift/venv/bin/target-redshift", line 8, in <module> cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.534762Z [info     ]     sys.exit(main())           cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.536306Z [info     ]   File "/home/zaki1272/meltano-projects/my-meltano-project/.meltano/loaders/target-redshift/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/target_redshift/__init__.py", line 444, in main cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.538902Z [info     ]     table_cache = load_table_cache(config) cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.539586Z [info     ]   File "/home/zaki1272/meltano-projects/my-meltano-project/.meltano/loaders/target-redshift/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/target_redshift/__init__.py", line 107, in load_table_cache cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.540105Z [info     ]     db = DbSync(config)        cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.540424Z [info     ]   File "/home/zaki1272/meltano-projects/my-meltano-project/.meltano/loaders/target-redshift/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/target_redshift/db_sync.py", line 253, in __init__ cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.542914Z [info     ]     aws_session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name=aws_profile) cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.543481Z [info     ]   File "/home/zaki1272/meltano-projects/my-meltano-project/.meltano/loaders/target-redshift/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 80, in __init__ cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.545654Z [info     ]     self._setup_loader()       cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.546640Z [info     ]   File "/home/zaki1272/meltano-projects/my-meltano-project/.meltano/loaders/target-redshift/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 120, in _setup_loader cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.547251Z [info     ]     self._loader = self._session.get_component('data_loader') cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.552048Z [info     ]   File "/home/zaki1272/meltano-projects/my-meltano-project/.meltano/loaders/target-redshift/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 682, in get_component cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.554759Z [info     ]     return self._components.get_component(name) cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.555653Z [info     ]   File "/home/zaki1272/meltano-projects/my-meltano-project/.meltano/loaders/target-redshift/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 919, in get_component cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.557703Z [info     ]     self._components[name] = factory() cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.558256Z [info     ]   File "/home/zaki1272/meltano-projects/my-meltano-project/.meltano/loaders/target-redshift/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 155, in <lambda> cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.558616Z [info     ]     lambda:  create_loader(self.get_config_variable('data_path'))) cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.558905Z [info     ]   File "/home/zaki1272/meltano-projects/my-meltano-project/.meltano/loaders/target-redshift/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 237, in get_config_variable cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.559472Z [info     ]     return self.get_component('config_store').get_config_variable( cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.559791Z [info     ]   File "/home/zaki1272/meltano-projects/my-meltano-project/.meltano/loaders/target-redshift/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/configprovider.py", line 293, in get_config_variable cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.567817Z [info     ]     return provider.provide()  cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.568722Z [info     ]   File "/home/zaki1272/meltano-projects/my-meltano-project/.meltano/loaders/target-redshift/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/configprovider.py", line 390, in provide cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.571307Z [info     ]     value = provider.provide() cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.571894Z [info     ]   File "/home/zaki1272/meltano-projects/my-meltano-project/.meltano/loaders/target-redshift/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/configprovider.py", line 451, in provide cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.572198Z [info     ]     scoped_config = self._session.get_scoped_config() cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.577180Z [info     ]   File "/home/zaki1272/meltano-projects/my-meltano-project/.meltano/loaders/target-redshift/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 337, in get_scoped_config cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.577976Z [info     ]     raise ProfileNotFound(profile=profile_name) cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.578632Z [info     ] botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (aws_profile) could not be found cmd_type=loader job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=target-redshift run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.692226Z [error    ] Loading failed                 code=1 job_id=shopify-to-redshift message=botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (aws_profile) could not be found name=meltano run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a
2022-03-17T07:37:05.693296Z [info     ] ELT could not be completed: Loader failed. cmd_type=elt job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=meltano run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.693550Z [info     ] For more detailed log messages re-run the command using 'meltano --log-level=debug ...' CLI flag. cmd_type=elt job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=meltano run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.693773Z [info     ] Note that you can also check the generated log file at '/home/zaki1272/meltano-projects/my-meltano-project/.meltano/logs/elt/shopify-to-redshift/c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a/elt.log'. cmd_type=elt job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=meltano run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
2022-03-17T07:37:05.693937Z [info     ] For more information on debugging and logging: https://docs.meltano.com/reference/command-line-interface#debugging cmd_type=elt job_id=shopify-to-redshift name=meltano run_id=c4b17452-4a71-4400-bde2-41c91aae043a stdio=stderr
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you pass the credentials?
`The config profile (aws_profile) could not be found`
So normally there is sth wrong with the profile you use. Is the AWS Redshift in a private subnet or is it public?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Nick, I figured out the issue. Now my EL pipeline is working.

Comment: I made some changes within AWS, like associating IAM role with my redshift cluster, setting inbound rules, and changing the network settings to public. I also generated AWS accesskeyID and AWSsecretkey and used them in my loader configuration. And lastly, I removed aws_profile from my config because it was not needed.